# PHP PDO creating tables

Tags: php, pdo

When I use some basic query, like `SELECT * FROM users` PDO::query() works and it returns
`object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(19) "SELECT * FROM users" }` and I can continue using this, but when I use query to create table the return of the function is bool(false).The query is valid and its executed correct, but the result is .. false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but for CREATE, shouldn't you be using exec, not query?

Comment: Exec actually returns the rows, and I realised that after creating the table there is nothing to return.Thanks. :)